# Strengthening Central Limit Theorem to Convergence of Mean for Specific Case

Tags: central-limit-theorem, uniform-integrability

The problem is as follows: Given two players, each flips a coin that produces heads with probability $p$. This is repeated $n$ times. What is the asymptotic behavior of the expected absolute total difference of heads?

This problem has numerous, slightly less general variants that have been "solved" online using the central limit theorem. Unfortunately, convergence in distribution does not guarantee convergence of means, yet this seems to be a common assumption in using normal distributions to approximate such a mean. The argument is as follows:

Suppose $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ are both sets of $n$ Bernoulli random variables, then by the central limit theorem,

\begin{align}
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,1)
\end{align}
Taking the difference of normals and then folding the distribution gives
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \right|
\overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}},2\left(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)\right)
\end{align}

I would like to conclude that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right|}{\sqrt{n}}
= 2\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{\pi}}
\end{align}

**Attempt**

To strengthen convergence in distribution to convergence of means it suffices to show uniform integrability. I found an explicit formula for the expected value at each $n$ using a random walk and the law of total expectation.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left| \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right| 
= 2p(1-p) \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j}^2 p^{2j}(1-p)^{2i-2j}
\end{align}

In the special case of $p=\frac{1}{2}$ this has a simple form:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbb{E}\left| \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right|
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}\sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j}^2
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{\binom{2i}{i}}{4^i}
= \frac{\Gamma(n+\tfrac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi n} \Gamma(n)}
\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align}

I could not find a simple closed form for general $p$ however. Is there an easier way to show uniform integrability, so that the CLT result may be justified?

**Edit**

The explanation of the calculated mean is as follows:

If we suppose that $X_i$ and $Y_i$ represent whether a step is taken in the (0,1) or (1,0) direction on a lattice grid. The excess $|\sum_{i=1}(X_i-Y_i)|$ may then be seen to be $|a-b|$, where the path ended on $(a,b)$.

For any path that ends off the diagonal (i.e., when we end on $(j,k)$ for $j\neq k \in \{0,1,\dotsc,n\}$), the mean increment is $0$. This is true because with probability $p^2+(1-p)^2$ the excess is zero, with probability $p(1-p)$ the excess decreases by $1$, and with probability $p(1-p)$ the excess increases by $1$.

For any path that ends on the diagonal (i.e., when we end on $(k,k)$ for some $k \in \{0,1,\dotsc,n\}$), then with probability $p^2+(1-p)^2$ the excess is zero, and with probability $2p(1-p)$ the excess increases by $1$, i.e., $(k+1,k)$ and $(k,k+1)$ are both increase excess by 1.

The summation then comes from counting all walks terminating on the diagonal before the $n$th movement, where the mean increments are non-zero.

**Final Solution**

Let $\varepsilon_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$. Let $G(t)=t^2$, then by de la Vallée-Poussin theorem, $\left\{\frac{\varepsilon_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right\}$ is uniformly integrable if

\begin{align}
\sup_n \mathbb{E}\left[ \left|\frac{\varepsilon_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|^2 \right]
< \infty
\end{align}

We calculate $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_n^2]$ explicitly. Noting that $\varepsilon_n = \varepsilon_{n-1}+X_{n-1}-Y_{n-1}$,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_n^2] 
= \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_{n-1}^2] 
+ 2\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_{n-1}] \mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}-Y_{n-1}] 
+ \mathbb{E}[ (X_{n-1}-Y_{n-1})^2 ]
\end{align}

Now, because $X_{n-1}$ and $Y_{n-1}$ are i.i.d, it follows that $\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}-Y_{n-1}]=0$.

We find that $(X_{n-1}-Y_{n-1})^2 = 1$ if $X_{n-1}=1$ and $Y_{n-1}=0$, or if $X_{n-1}=0$ and $Y_{n-1}=1$, each of which occurs with probability $p(1-p)$, hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_n^2]
= \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_{n-1}^2] + 2p(1-p)
= 2np(1-p)
\end{align}

It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \left|\frac{\varepsilon_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|^2 \right]
= \frac{1}{n}[2np(1-p)]
= 2p(1-p) < \infty
\end{align}

Uniform integrability strengthens convergence in distribution to convergence in mean, which implies convergence of means.

Comment: Which kind of dependence the sequence $\left(X_i-Y_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ does satisfy?

Comment: All $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are i.i.d, so their difference is independent.

Comment: It is true if the sequences $\left(X_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ and  $\left(Y_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ are independent. In this case, the uniform integrability of the sequence $\left|\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-Y_i\right| /\sqrt n$ follows from its boundedness in $\mathbb L^2$ (since the increments have mean zero and are uncorrelated).

Comment: I added an edit to explain why the increments do not necessarily have mean zero. Basically if $|\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)|=0$ then the increment is not of mean zero.

Comment: I have just realized that the mean increment is maximized at $p=1/ 2 $, at every turn, which I showed was bounded. Hence we obtain uniform integrability and therefore converges in the way intended.

I will update the question/answer accordingly.

Comment: I missed the fact that $X_i$ and $Y_i$ do not have the same parameter. Maybe you could put what you wrote as a final solution in an answer. In this way, we will be able to upvote it.